# Visual Studio 2022 autocompletion and pasting breaks formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have recently switched from Visual Studio 2019 to 2022 and am working on a C# project that uses tab and indent size 3. I used [the same tabs settings for both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfeLx.png).

For some reason I can't figure out however, VS 2022 breaks indentation below any block of code that has been pasted or auto-completed. It looks like it is attempting to reformat with a size 4 indentation but I could be wrong on that (see here [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ueg17.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy1zL.png) auto-complete).

I have not used an `.editorconfig` file and could not find one anywhere in the folder structure. I have also tried disabling all my extensions and resetting my settings to no avail. Does anyone have an idea what might be the cause here?

**EDIT**

Since then I have tried the suggestions of [Lei Zhang-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19849709/lei-zhang-msft) but playing with the 'format on paste' and 'adaptive formatting' parameters did not change anything and creating an `.editorconfig` file from the 'Add item' menu doesn't seem to do anything (it didn't show an error but did not create the file). I have also attempted a repair and a full reinstall but that didn't change anything so it seems likely that this is somehow related to the project itself.

**SOLUTION**

I can now confirm that it was indeed a bug as [Jiale Xue - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16764901/jiale-xue-msft) suggested. Updating to VS2022 17.4.2 solved the issue.

Comment: You should turn on whitespace symbols - it'll at least make it easier to see what could be going on.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't show much other than the fact that the number of spaces increased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the Visual Studio 17.4.1.

A fix for this issue has been internally implemented and is being prepared for [release](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2022-174:-C-editor-always-uses-Smar/10195742).

Comment: That does seem interesting. I'll update as soon as the new version comes out. Hopefully this will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the EditorConfig file to the project.

1.From the menu bar, choose Project > Add New Item

2.In the search box, search for editorconfig.

[image]

Reference Links：

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2022

Another method：

In Tools->Options disable Automatic formatting on paste and Use adaptive formatting
[image]

[image]

Hope it can help you

Comment: I attempted both but unfortunately these didn't do the trick. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: ok, I will look into this issue and update the answer.